# Is it safe to rely on next context in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

In React 15.4.1 the next context is provided as a third argument of `shouldComponentUpdate()` method. Is it safe to rely on it to decide if component should update?

It perfectly suits for the our current needs (working with forms validation messages), but I'm not sure if API will not change in the future and context will be removed from component's update process. For now, the third parameter of `shouldComponentUpdate` [is not mentioned](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) in the docs for some reason.

Will be great to hear from React devs about it. Thanks!

Comment: context, in general, AFAIK, is not fully documented because it might change.

Comment: If it makes the most sense to use it for a situation and you have tried alternatives then you should. That's why it's there.